# AppTheme Change font family depend on language change localization in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app, all things are working fine, I have two buttons that translates the app from english, Urdu and arabic, I made an AppTheme dart file and call it inside main, I gave it case of 'ar' language code, but it is not working, it always except (else) condition, help me please.

Here is the code:

inside main dart file, I returned material app inside build widget:

```
   theme: AppTheme.lightTheme, 
   supportedLocales: LanguageDataModel.languageLocales(), ...etc
```

inside AppTheme file, I found this code in chatGPT for language if,else case:

```
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
       fontFamily:
        appStore.selectedLanguage.validate(value: default_Language) == 'ar'
            ? 'Cairo'
            : 'RobotoCondensed',
   )...etc
```

I have defined default_Language='en' variable inside constants file, does it have to do anything with validate constructor?

where is my error, is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppTheme extends ThemeData {
  @override
  TextTheme textTheme(TextTheme base) {
    final locale = window.locale;

    // Set the font family depending on the current locale.
    if (locale.languageCode == 'en') {
      return base.copyWith(fontFamily: 'Roboto');
    } else if (locale.languageCode == 'ar') {
      return base.copyWith(fontFamily: 'Cairo');
    } else {
      return base.copyWith(fontFamily: 'Roboto');
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: AppTheme(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('This text will be displayed in the current locale\'s font family.'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```